# C#/VB.Net How to collapse specific values in a list

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
AAAA    a       07-02-2022
BBBB    a       07-02-2022
CCCC    a       07-02-2022
DDDD    a       07-02-2022
EEEE    a       07-02-2022
AAAA    b       07-02-2022
```

I have a list like the above, how do I collapse(or take the first) when column 1 is "AAAA" or "BBBB", and the column2/column3 values are the same.
This rule only applies to "AAAA" and "BBBB".
I was thinking to group by column2/column3, and then I don't know what exactly I should proceed.

```
        Dim collapsed = list.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Column2 + x.Column3)
```

The results I want is : (Second line of BBBB was removed)

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
AAAA    a       07-02-2022
CCCC    a       07-02-2022
DDDD    a       07-02-2022
EEEE    a       07-02-2022
AAAA    b       07-02-2022
```

Comment: You are adding instead of OR'ing : x.Column2 + x.Column3.  In c# use | and in VB.net use OR

Comment: Perhaps using a HashSet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) method:

```
Imports ConsoleApp1

Module Module1

    Class X
        Property Column1 As String
        Property Column2 As String
        Property Column3 As String

        Sub New()
            ' Empty constructor
        End Sub

        Sub New(a As String, b As String, c As String)
            Column1 = a
            Column2 = b
            Column3 = c
        End Sub

        Public Shared Operator =(a As X, b As X) As Boolean
            If IsSpecialColumn(a.Column1) AndAlso IsSpecialColumn(b.Column1) Then
                Return (a.Column2 = b.Column2) AndAlso (a.Column3 = b.Column3)
            End If
            Return False
        End Operator

        Public Shared Operator <>(a As X, b As X) As Boolean
            If IsSpecialColumn(a.Column1) AndAlso IsSpecialColumn(b.Column1) Then
                Return (a.Column2 <> b.Column2) OrElse (a.Column3 <> b.Column3)
            End If
            Return False
        End Operator

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return $"{Column1} {Column2} {Column3}"
        End Function

    End Class

    Public Class XComparer
        Implements IEqualityComparer(Of X)

        Public Function Equals1(ByVal a As X, ByVal b As X) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of X).Equals

            Return a = b

        End Function

        Public Function GetHashCode1(ByVal a As X) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of X).GetHashCode

            If a Is Nothing Then Return 0

            If IsSpecialColumn(a.Column1) Then
                Return a.Column2.GetHashCode() Xor a.Column3.GetHashCode()
            End If

            Return a.Column1.GetHashCode() Xor a.Column2.GetHashCode() Xor a.Column3.GetHashCode()

        End Function

    End Class

    Function IsSpecialColumn(c As String) As Boolean
        Return c = "AAAA" OrElse c = "BBBB"
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim q As New List(Of X) From {New X("AAAA", "a", "07-02-2022"),
                                      New X("BBBB", "a", "07-02-2022"),
                                      New X("CCCC", "a", "07-02-2022"),
                                      New X("DDDD", "a", "07-02-2022"),
                                      New X("EEEE", "a", "07-02-2022"),
                                      New X("AAAA", "b", "07-02-2022")}

        Dim r = q.Distinct(New XComparer())

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, r))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
AAAA a 07-02-2022
CCCC a 07-02-2022
DDDD a 07-02-2022
EEEE a 07-02-2022
AAAA b 07-02-2022
```

*However,* I do not know if it will always remove later occurrences in preference to an earlier one.